# Montando um Web Scraping com Python

Tags: web-scraping

tudo bem? Pois bem, sou um entusiasta de programção, e peguei um tutorial para fazer webscraping. A lógica eu até entendi, porém estou enfrentando um problema quando um dos dados estão faltando no site, abaixo deixo o código e minha analise do problema enfrentado:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.classcentral.com/subject/data-science"
page = requests.get(URL)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


Course = []
Duration = []
Start_Date = []
Offered_By = []
No_Of_Reviews = []
Rating = []

def find_2nd(string, substring):
    return string.find(substring, string.find(substring) + 1)

def find_1st(string, substring):
    return string.find(substring, string.find(substring))

for i in soup.findAll("span",{'class' : 'text-1 weight-semi line-tight'}):
    b = str(i)
       
    #print(b  [  find_1st(b,'>')+1  :  find_2nd(b,'<')  ]  )
    Course.append(b[find_1st(b,'>')+1:find_2nd(b,'<')])

course = []
for i in Course:
    i = i.strip()
    print(i)
    course.append(i)


# # Num of Reviews
for i in soup.findAll("span",{'class' : 'large-down-hidden block line-tight text-4 color-gray'}):
    b = str(i)
    print(b[find_1st(b,'>')+1:find_2nd(b,'<')])
    No_Of_Reviews.append(b[find_1st(b,'>')+1:find_2nd(b,'<')])
```

Pois bem, entrando no site e fazendo uma busca, existe um curso que encontra-se sem reviews. O problema disso tudo, é que quando vou transformar isso em um DataFrame, ocorre o erro de length. Ou seja, não consigo gerar o DataFrame, por causa desse valor faltante. Não coloquei o código completo para não ficar mais extenso, por que o restante esta dando certo.

Alguém saberia me ajudar ? Como faria para que o código entendensse que essa informação não existe, coloque o valor de 0 e continue com a implementação do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que causa esse problema é que os elementos sem reviews e os elementos com várias reviews têm classes completamente diferentes. Seguem dois exemplos que eu tirei da página:

```html
<span class="large-down-hidden block line-tight text-4 color-gray">24 Reviews</span>

<span class="medium-down-hidden text-4 color-gray italic">No reviews yet.</span>
```

Então eu modifiquei o programa pra checar se um elemento tem as classes do primeiro do exemplo, porque esse é o caso mais comum. Se não tiver, o programa procura por um elemento com as classes `medium-down-hidden text-4 color-gray italic`, porque isso indica que ele não tem nenhuma review.

Você também não precisa usar as funções `find_1st` e `find_2nd` pra ler o texto dentro do elemento `span`, porque é muito mais fácil digitar só `nome_do_objeto.text`. O resultado é o mesmo.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.classcentral.com/subject/data-science"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

td_list = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "hide-on-hover fill-space relative"})
for i, td in enumerate(td_list):
    try: # Classe com > 0 reviews
        reviews = True
        my_span = td.findChildren("span", {"class" : "large-down-hidden block line-tight text-4 color-gray"})[0]
    except IndexError: # Classe com 0 reviews
        reviews = False
        my_span = td.findChildren("span", {"class" : "medium-down-hidden text-4 color-gray italic"})[0]

    output = " ".join(my_span.text.split())

    if reviews:
        print(i, "\t", output)
    else:
        print(i, "\t", output, "<-- No reviews!")
```

Comment: Nossa Krossbow, muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo. Obrigado mesmo.